# Why do I have a TypeError in Gitlab CI but not on my machine when running jest?

Tags: javascript, regex, jestjs, gitlab-ci

I'm using the following snippet to extract some info from a string, which seems to work fine:

```js
const str="dialect://user:password@host:port/name";
const regex=/([^\:]*)\:\/\/([^\:]*)\:([^\@]*)\@([^\:]*)\:([^\/]*)\/(.*)/
let [, DB_DIALECT, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_NAME] = regex.exec(str);
console.log(DB_DIALECT);
console.log(DB_USER);
console.log(DB_PASSWORD);
console.log(DB_HOST);
console.log(DB_PORT);
console.log(DB_NAME);
```

As you can see above, it is working by itself. I have some unit tests that I can execute with no error on my machine. However when I run the same tests in Gitlab CI, I get the following error

```
$ npm run test

> express-api@1.0.0 test /builds/organization/enoapp/folder
> jest --runInBand --forceExit spec

FAIL spec/api.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: regex.exec is not a function or its return value is not iterable

      14 | // Extract info from env variable
      15 | const regex=/([^\:]*)\:\/\/([^\:]*)\:([^\@]*)\@([^\:]*)\:([^\/]*)\/(.*)/
    > 16 | let [, DB_DIALECT, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_NAME] = regex.exec(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
         |
```

Why does the same seemingly correct code produce errors on Gitlab CI?

I thought it might be because of what's inside `process.env.DATABASE_URL` but wouldn't that cause a `regex.exec(...) is null` error instead?

Comment: It's most definitely `process.env.DATABASE_URL` not being the same as `str`. The error is kind of weird, but there was a time when you didn't get very useful error messages on destructuring.

Comment: @MinusFour Yeah, you're actually right, my dotenv file for tests was in my gitignore so it didn't load env variables and caused this error. It is not the clearest error message I've ever encountered... You can add this as an answer if you'd like me to accept it

Comment: I just pointed out where the error was, you came up with the solution, so you are better writing the answer of why did it happen and how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out [MinusFour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1549541/minusfour) was right in saying that `process.env.DATABASE_URL` was the culprit despite the weird error:

- I had this variable defined in a test-specific dotenv file that was in my gitignore
- Removing it from the gitignore and pushing solved the issue
- I'm still unsure of why I got this error instead of `regex.exec(...) is null` which I would have expected running regex.exec on an `undefined` variable.